# Program to convert the given pixels length into width and height

Tags: java, image, pixel

I have a input which is in pixels (image pixels), like for example 24 pixels, my problem is to convert them to width and height of the buffered image, for the input 24, I can't just use 1 height x 24 width, it will become too long width, that means the output should be like 6 width x 4 height which has 24 pixels in it. Is it possible to do so in java? I think I explained my question properly...

Comment: OK, 24 pixels != 1Hx24W,  but why especially 6Wx4H?  Why not, say 3Wx8H?   Anything's possible to compute, if you know (and can explain) what is to be computed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brute-force: Start in the middle (at the square root), then try from there until a valid split is found, using the `%` remainder operator.

```
static int optimumHeight(int areaSize) {
    if (areaSize <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("areaSize must be positive: " + areaSize);
    for (int h = (int) Math.sqrt(areaSize); h > 1; h--)
        if (areaSize % h == 0)
            return h;
    return 1;
}
```

*Test*

```java
for (int areaSize = 20; areaSize < 30; areaSize++) {
    int height = optimumHeight(areaSize);
    int width = areaSize / height;
    System.out.printf("%d -> %dWx%dH%n", areaSize, width, height);
}
```

*Output*

```
20 -> 5Wx4H
21 -> 7Wx3H
22 -> 11Wx2H
23 -> 23Wx1H
24 -> 6Wx4H
25 -> 5Wx5H
26 -> 13Wx2H
27 -> 9Wx3H
28 -> 7Wx4H
29 -> 29Wx1H
```

---

**UPDATE**

When `areaSize` is a prime number, the result is always `areaSize x 1H`. A comment *(now deleted)* requested that to be changed to use an `areaSize` that is one larger:

```java
static int optimumHeight(int areaSize) {
    if (areaSize <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("areaSize must be positive: " + areaSize);
    if (areaSize <= 2)
        return 1;
    for (int h = (int) Math.sqrt(areaSize); h > 1; h--)
        if (areaSize % h == 0)
            return h;
    int altSize = areaSize + 1;
    for (int h = (int) Math.sqrt(altSize); h > 2; h--)
        if (altSize % h == 0)
            return h;
    return 2;
}
```

The `width` calculation needs to be adjusted to round up, so it becomes:

```java
int width = (areaSize + height - 1) / height;
```

*Examples*

```
1 -> 1Wx1H
2 -> 2Wx1H
3 -> 2Wx2H
4 -> 2Wx2H
5 -> 3Wx2H
6 -> 3Wx2H
7 -> 4Wx2H
8 -> 4Wx2H
9 -> 3Wx3H
10 -> 5Wx2H
11 -> 4Wx3H
12 -> 4Wx3H
13 -> 7Wx2H
14 -> 7Wx2H
15 -> 5Wx3H
16 -> 4Wx4H
17 -> 6Wx3H
18 -> 6Wx3H
19 -> 5Wx4H
20 -> 5Wx4H
21 -> 7Wx3H
22 -> 11Wx2H
23 -> 6Wx4H
24 -> 6Wx4H
25 -> 5Wx5H
26 -> 13Wx2H
27 -> 9Wx3H
28 -> 7Wx4H
29 -> 6Wx5H
```

Comment: Sorry I mean 30, it was a typo

Comment: Not sure I understand this. Just because you have 24 pixels, it doesn't follow that it is a 6x4 image. It may be 4x6, or 3x8 or 8x3 or 12x2 or something else so it is still going to look wrong, surely?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Perhaps you should make that point to OP in the question. This is an answer to the question. What OP wants to do with the result is up to OP. --- Actually, Kevin Anderson already made that [point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64609346/program-to-convert-the-given-pixels-length-into-width-and-height/64609729?noredirect=1#comment114240787_64609346), so ...